# How can i display the list of grades of 4 students while rounding them up using Python 3.6

Tags: python, for-loop, variable-assignment

```
n = int(input("please type number of students and their grades>>>"))
grades = []

def solve_for(grades):
    for i in grades(4):
        if grades_item >= 38:
            if grades_item % 5 == 3:
                grades_item += 2
            elif grades_item % 5 == 4:
                grades_item += 1
        else:
            print(grades_item)

for i in range(n):
    grades_item = int(input())
    grades.append(grades_item)

result = solve_for(grades)
```

am I doing something wrong?
Trying to get user to input 4 numbers 73, 67, 38, 33 and produce a list that rounds those number based on the if function for-loop

The rules include:

1. If the difference between the grade and the next multiple of 5 is less than 3, round grade up to next multiple of 5
2. If the value of grade is less than 38,  no rounding occurs as the result will still be a failing grade.

Comment: Please confirm that the indentation is correct now after my edit. I *think* this is what your code really looks like, but of course I could be wrong.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you posted? Does it throw an exception? Does it produce incorrect output?

Comment: "*Unable to run*"  please show what happens, including any error messages.

Comment: There are at least 3 different problems in this code, and fixing them all is beyond the scope of SO. We need you to ask a specific question about your code, otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: _"Unable to run"_ should be a particular error and consequently question

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thank you for the edit, it was initially like this but I get 
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement after running that.

Comment: Sounds easily googleable. According to [SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement](//stackoverflow.com/q/21226808) that would happen if you paste this code into an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

I posted two fixes next to the two comments. Why did you have the 4 in `grades(4)` though?

**Sorry, couldn't post the question as a comment as I don't have enough reputation.

```
n = int(input("please type number of students and their grades>>>"))
grades = []

def solve_for(grades):
    for i in grades: # Grades is not callable as it is a list
        if grades_item >= 38:
            if grades_item % 5 == 3:
                grades_item += 2
            elif grades_item % 5 == 4:
                grades_item += 1
            print(grades_item) # to print it after your edits?
        else:
            print(grades_item)

for i in range(n):
    grades_item = int(input())
    grades.append(grades_item)

result = solve_for(grades)
```